# Canvas optimization when pixel changes are known

Tags: javascript

I am currently working on a web application where only single pixel changes are known, which are implemented like an event:

`function pixelChanged(x, y, color)`

These need to be drawn to a canvas. I have tried two methods to accomplish this:

1. draw pixels directly with fillRect
2. memorize pixels and put them on the canvas with putImageData every few microseconds

Now both of these methods seem to have a poor performance. The first one results in many redraws, the second one redraws the whole image, even if only a little area changed.

My specific question is, if there is a better method to implement this (maybe something like 1., but in some way delayed ?).

And if not, which method of these should I prefer ? How can I optimize it in this case ?

Thanks in advance and best regards,

copy

Comment: Have you tried using getImageData(), modifying the pixels there, and then putImageData() when you're ready?

Comment: in case of 1. do the calls to pixelchanged occur in the same 'call cycle', or is there a delay between them (settimout,userinput, etc.)? You might try double buffering. Drawing to an offscreen canvas, and copy the entire canvas to the visible one every few second. Not sure if it will improve on your method no 2.

Comment: @JamesClark No I didn't. This is really a nice improvement. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach I took is to break a large image into an NxN grid and redraw the specific areas that have changed.  I found a decent size that balances the # of redraws vs the size of a redraw to be around 50x50px.  If you need the exact optimal number for maximum px/sec drawn, I have it somewhere from benchmarks.

So if you have a 60x60 change, you'd be re-drawing between 4 and 9 50x50 squares.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this [article](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/) with different approaches for canvas-optimization. I'd suggest you to combine several optimizations and see how it goes. Please note that our eye doesn't recognize frequent pixel changes on big area, so it make sense to buffer your pixel changes and draw several changes at once. Also please note that browser need several milliseconds to apply your changes, so don't make interval too small.